# Wrecked my partitions with testdisk

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery, testdisk, data-loss

I used to have partitions for Windows and Linux(had dual-boot) on my SSD, but then I broke the partitions with testdisk (because I didn't know what I was doing).

And now it looks like this:

[image: disk gui]

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

Prints:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 57DA974A-6616-4D5B-A6C1-D1878D6653F2

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   11416512  11419391      2880   1.4M EFI System
/dev/sda2   12620768  12623647      2880   1.4M EFI System
/dev/sda3   22598488  22601367      2880   1.4M EFI System
/dev/sda4   26751712  26754591      2880   1.4M EFI System
/dev/sda5   56217864  56220743      2880   1.4M EFI System
/dev/sda6   56220744  56223623      2880   1.4M EFI System
/dev/sda7   60957632  60960511      2880   1.4M EFI System
/dev/sda8   96417586  97789569   1371984 669.9M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  126886816 126889695      2880   1.4M EFI System
/dev/sda10 140851301 149296322   8445022     4G Apple HFS/HFS+
/dev/sda11 199096632 209549623  10452992     5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda12 328030206 498274301 170244096  81.2G Linux filesystem
```

I was able to boot my computer from my bootable Ubuntu USB ("Try before installing").

I'm not sure how (and if) I could recover my previous state.

Edit, additional info:

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda

Partition table scan:
  MBR: hybrid
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present
Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 500118192 sectors, 238.5 GiB
Model: SAMSUNG MZNLN256
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 57DA974A-6616-4D5B-A6C1-D1878D6653F2
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 500118158
Partitions will be aligned on 1-sector boundaries
Total free space is 309580991 sectors (147.6 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1        11416512        11419391   1.4 MiB     EF00  EFI System Partition
   2        12620768        12623647   1.4 MiB     EF00  EFI System Partition
   3        22598488        22601367   1.4 MiB     EF00  EFI System Partition
   4        26751712        26754591   1.4 MiB     EF00  EFI System Partition
   5        56217864        56220743   1.4 MiB     EF00  EFI System Partition
   6        56220744        56223623   1.4 MiB     EF00  EFI System Partition
   7        60957632        60960511   1.4 MiB     EF00  EFI System Partition
   8        96417586        97789569   669.9 MiB   8300  
   9       126886816       126889695   1.4 MiB     EF00  EFI System Partition
  10       140851301       149296322   4.0 GiB     AF00  
  11       199096632       209549623   5.0 GiB     8300  
  12       328030206       498274301   81.2 GiB    8300
```

Comment: If you can't find technical support here I would email developer / post bug on their website.

Comment: Does gdisk show same partitions? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`